# Social Popup Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying create something so that when the user gets to the end of the page they get a div popup.

For some reason it's working in Internet Explorer but in Chrome it doesnt. I'm thinking because the top() element:

```
<span id="myPara"></span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($('#myPara').offset().top < $(this).height() + $(this).scrollTop()) {
            $('#msgBox').show();
            $('#msgBox').animate({top:$(window).scrollTop()+"px" },{queue: false, duration: 350});
            } else {
            $('#msgBox').hide();
            }
        });
</script>
```

can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: It might be useful to do a console.log on the two figures you are comparing, to see if the if statement is ever satisfied.

Comment: I did, but for some reason in crhome the vars gets another values from explorer...

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said it sounds like you need to adjust your parameters in order for the if statement to be satisfied.  Chrome obviously has a different view port.  Through testing you should be able to find the optimal size.